# Formula/Alerter to signify ind in work

Tags: business-objects

I would like to create a yes/no column in Business Objects (Boxi).

I have a job start date and a job end date data columns.

If a person is in work then the new column should say yes. 
If they have a start and finish, it suggests, they are not in work.

I can just add two columns and physically look to see if there is an end date. But I don't want the two columns in my report.
I just want ind_name and in_work

Answer (score 1):

I use Webi and am not familiar with Boxi. But you should be able to reference objects without needing to display them in your report. I'd use IsNull.

```
=If(IsNull([FinishDate]) And Not(IsNull([StartDate]))) Then "In work" Else "Not in work"
```

If your object isn't technically null, your workaround would be the Length or IsDate formula, depending on whether your dates are in date or string formula.

```
=if(Length([StartDate])>1) AND Length([EndDate])<=1 Then "In work" Else "Not in work"
=If(IsDate([StartDate])) And Not(IsDate([EndDate])) Then 1
```

If you don't need to check for a start date you could cut your formula down even shorter.

```
=if(IsNull([FinishDate]) Then "In work" Else "Not in work"
```